# Given a subgroup $H $, find a normal subgroup of $G$ with index less than or equal to $n!$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup with finite index $n$.  Prove that $G$ has a normal subgroup $N$ such that $N\subseteq H$and $|G: N| \le n!$.

Comment: This was on an old qualification exam and also given to me without any context other than being a group theory problem.  I will try to edit it when I get a chance.

Comment: -2?  Stack Exchange is ruthless.

Answer (score 4):

$G$ acts on $G/H$ by left multiplication and this action is sujective, you deduce a morphism $f:G\rightarrow S_n$ which is not trivial, take $N$ the kernel of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show any self work so I can't know what you've tried and what you know, so  I'll give the answer and you find out whether it is true and its properties:

$$N=\bigcap_{g\in G} g^{-1}Hg$$

and it gets even better, since in fact $\;N\lhd G\;$ .

Comment: I was clueless and didn't know what direction to take.  I had been staring at the problem for too long.

Comment: Where did you find the problem, and what things had been talked about in the book / class recently? (For instance, this is an early proposition in Isaacs' *Finite Group Theory*; I do think that if you haven't seen the proof, it can be tricky to come up with). That's usually a good way to include context, since "naked" problem statements are generally not well-received.

Comment: It's on a past exam.  I am studying for my qualification exam.  I stated the problem as it appears in the exam.  I left out, "N has finite index," but I thought that was obvious from the inequality.